Do these brown rings indicate water damage?
I'm thinking of buying this house, but I'm sceptical because of these spots on the ceiling. The appraiser says it "might just be from cigarette smoke".



What are we looking at? Is that a porch ceiling? (It's certainly not a roof.) What material is it? What weather exposure does it have? Please revise to offer more information.

The "so called appraiser" is full of organic fertilizer, and evidently works for the seller, not you. If supposedly working for you, they are incompetent, or getting paid by the buyer to give you bad advice.

It looks like you are looking at the ceiling.  Those spots look a lot like water  stains.  I would recommend that you hire an inspector to look at the house.  I always do.  Its the most precious thing you will buy!
If the appraiser is a building inspector, I would get another one.

They do look like water stains, but without more information we don't know whether it's "damage". Could just be from damp weather condensation.

It's from water of some sort, without more information it's hard to say why it's there though, it might be condensation, or it might be leaking from above. Is this an interior room or something like a porch?
I suppose the water might be collecting cigarette residue, or honestly just dirt, making it look darker than normal, vs something like mold, this might be what the inspector was talking about.
